# Группировка данных из одной таблицы на основании данных другой таблицы

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Есть DataFrame, `Материалы` являются индексом. Таблица примерно следующая:

```
   Материалы              Поставщик       Дата поставки              Отклонение  
    Перчатки                  А             01.02.18                     5.00
    Анкер                     В             02.02.18                     6.00
    Бур                       С             03.05.18                     3.50
    Перчатки                  А             04.06.18                     4.00
```

и т.д.

В переменной `А` содержатся данные из  DataFrame, полученные с помощью группировки:

```
        Поставщик        Среднее отклонение
0          А                12.00
1          В                11.23
2          С                 9.02
3          D                22.16
```

Как сгруппировать данные для каждого из поставщиков попавшего в переменную `А`?

Группировку произвести из начального DataFrame и вывести данные для каждого поставщика в отдельную переменную. Количество поставщиков неизвестно.
`Per1` (переменная)

```
Материал          Поставщик   Дата поставки     Отклонение
Перчатки              А         01.02.18           5.00
Перчатки              А         04.06.18           4.00

Рer2

Анкер                 В         02.02.18           6.00
```

и т.д.

Для всех поставщиков попавших в переменную `А`. Если они не попали туда, то игнорировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно создать словарь с поставщиками в качестве ключей:

```
res = {a:b for a,b in df.query("`Поставщик` in @A.Поставщик").groupby("Поставщик")}
```

---

результат:

```
In [129]: res["А"]
Out[129]:
          Поставщик Дата поставки  Отклонение
Материалы
Перчатки          А      01.02.18         5.0
Перчатки          А      04.06.18         4.0

In [130]: res["В"]
Out[130]:
          Поставщик Дата поставки  Отклонение
Материалы
Анкер             В      02.02.18         6.0

In [131]: res["С"]
Out[131]:
          Поставщик Дата поставки  Отклонение
Материалы
Бур               С      03.05.18         3.5
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, не получается вывести результат в том виде в котором он у вас выводится. Если просто пишу res в командной строке, то выводит словарь полный. Если res['A'], то пишет : KeyError: 'A'

Comment: @VladVladov, это потому, что в __ваших__ примерах - большие __киррилические__ буквы (`а`, `в`, `с`), вместо латинских (`a`, `b`, `c`)

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду названия в колонке Поставщик? Ввожу res['А'] - на кириллице, результат тот же. Поясните пожалуйста

Comment: Используйте русскую букву "А" в вызове `res["А"]` или просто скорипуйте код из моего ответа. Я использлвал в ответе данные из вашего вопроса...